# Angular NgZone.runOutsideAngular and OnPush change detection strategy

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I'm trying to optimize the performance of code in angular application.

I know that I can `runOutsideAngular` some code in order not to cause change detection on each code run or event.

However, do I need to use `runOutsideAngular` when I utilize `OnPush` change detection strategy? (for listeners etc)

Comment: Do you have some decision? I am also interested in it...

Comment: @dark19 added my thoughts as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer now.

In my opinion it depends on what an app looks like.

- If it has *lots of unoptimized* components and the an *async operation* is going to *fire lots of times* or it's an event listener then it has to be within `runOutsideAngular`
- However, if an application is *mostly* built with components with `OnPush` strategy or simply `AppComponent` uses `OnPush` (as whole tree is going to be using `OnPush` strategy defining it on a top level component defines this strategy for the whole application irreversibly) then you can omit using `runOutsideAngular` as triggers for change detection won't affect anything

Also I think that there is an option for fully `OnPush` optimized app to disable all events patches from Zone thus there would be no need for `runOutsideAngular` as all async events have no point of triggering NgZone.